# Flush System.IO.MemoryStream to binary file from debugger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm debugging a library with only `dll` and `pdb` files available. I can see the source code and toggle breakpoints, but I can't modify the code. 
There's a method which creates `System.IO.MemoryStream` object and I want to flush it **as is** to a file. This `stream` has positive Length and Position>0, and I can output to screen from debugger by calling:

```
new System.IO.StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```

But I need to output it to a file, as it contains binary data and I need file for hex comparisons later. To do that I execute in debugger Watch tab:

```
stream.Position = 0
stream.CopyTo(new System.IO.FileStream("file.bin", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
stream.Position = 0
stream.CopyTo(new System.IO.FileStream("file2.bin", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write), (int)stream.Length)
```

in both cases empty files are created.

The library I'm debugging has this usings:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Xml;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump the MemoryStream to a file with a single command in the quickwatch window:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\file.bin", stream.ToArray())
```

Comment: `System.IO.MemoryStream` doesn't have `ToArray()` method.

Comment: @rfg It does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Calling `ToArray()` method returns: error CS1061: 'Stream' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'Stream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @rfg Then it means it's not a MemoryStream

Comment: Seems so, but debugger shows it as `System.IO.MemoryStream`

Comment: @rfg Have you tried casting it? `File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\file.bin", ((MemoryStream)stream).ToArray())`

Comment: Yes, that also didn't work. Finally solved by: `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("file.bin", new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream).ReadBytes((int)stream.Length))`

Comment: Thank you for your help!